# Run Selenium C# Test from a Window Form

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to launch my Selenium Launch when a button is press on my windows form. I am unsure on how to link the class library with the Windows Form. I am getting stuck because for the script/class to run correctly the project Output Type must be set to "Class Library" otherwise it gives out loads of errors.

Here is the class I am trying to launch :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SeleniumTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // Set what browser to use
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Selenium");

            // Set the base website
            string baseURL = "http://kd.svr-webdev-01.df.local";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/");

            driver.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you able to just `SeleniumTest test = new SeleniumTest(); test.TestMethod1();` ?

Comment: You have shown us a unit test. If you are trying to put it in a form, just take the body of `TestMethod1` and put in it a button click event on your form.

Comment: @Arran I am very silly. I didn't think that would work. Thanks Arran, works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is put your unit test (TestMethod1) body into a button click event. Easiest way to make that event is just to drop a button onto the form using the designer and double click it.

Visual Studio will create a blank event for you, and you just need to copy/paste your current code into there.

Even, to make it simpler, create a console application and stick that body into the the "Main" method.